# Iterate over string within list

Tags: python, list, loops

`lst = ["abc", "sassafrass", "bingo", "bass"]`

My problem that I need help with is that I want to iterate through each character and count characters within each string.  So I used the nested for loop......ex:

```
def multi_letter(s)
      for c in s:
          for l in c:
```

so basically I want to count each letter (`l`) in each word (`c`) in the list but organized as the word.....lets say that the letters have numerical value and I want to add them up...

I DON'T WANT THE ANSWER!!! Please help me find an answer......I'm lost and a beginner looking for understanding......Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Nested for loop is a good start. Make sure to use good variable names so things are not confusing. The first loop is of `item` in the `list`, the second loop of `character` in `item`

Comment: `ord(ltr)` i guess maybe? might be what your asking?

Comment: What do you want to do with the numeric value afterwards?

Comment: Personally, I would use the Counter class from the collections module, you're very close, have a think what to do with `l`

Comment: For clarification I want to find a way to evaluate each string within the list, separately.

Answer (score 0):

You are off to a good start. The nested loop will give you each letter from each word. One way to get the numeric value is using:

```
ord(l)
```

From the documentation:

> Given a string representing one Unicode character, return an integer
>   representing the Unicode code point of that character. For example,
>   `ord('a')` returns the integer `97`.

`97` is the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com) value of the `a`.

You can add these values up and you will get the numerical value of the word.

But that won't be very helpful. Consider a string `zz` - your sum will be `244`; and `QQR` will also give you `244`. This is just one of infinite possibilities.

Comment: the numerical value isn't the point here........its the organization of the output: abc = integer  sassafrass = integer and the problem with my nested loop approach is that it lists every letter seperately........any help?

Comment: Abc = what integer?!

Answer (score 0):

May be this code help you:

```
lst = ["abc", "sassafrass", "bingo", "bass"]
#make a empty list to store count
count=[] 
for i in range(len(lst)):
    count.append(len(lst[i]))
print(count)
```

Comment: My question to be put more clearly: How can I evaluate each string within the list separately?  Whether I am getting the sum of their numerical values or whatever.....how do i do it?